rust `split` split before the pattern match
I'm trying to split up a String retaining each pattern match but with the matched part retained as the beginning of the next sub-string rather than the terminator of the last.
Current implementation:
let s = String::from("AaaBbCc");
for block in s.split_inclusive(|c: char| c.is_uppercase()) {
    println!("{block}")
}


Current Output
A
aaB
bC
c

Desired output
Aaa
Bb
Cc

How can this be achieved?

@DanielA.White please at least read the question before putting in a close request, if you had read either question it would be clear that I know how to keep the separators. The current code does this and the current output shows that it does this it also uses split_inclusive which is the solution given in the question you link to. The question is about changing the location of the split (before vs after) not how to retain the matched character

I don't think the standard library can help you out there (though there's a million methods on String, I could be wrong). But it's a simple enough iterator to write yourself, if you really need the laziness:
struct CamelCaseSplit<'a> {
    char_indices: std::str::CharIndices<'a>,
    chunk_start: usize,
    s: &'a str
}

impl<'a> CamelCaseSplit<'a> {
    pub fn new(s: &'a str) -> Self {
        let mut char_indices = s.char_indices();
        // We'll never want to split before the first char, so skip it.
        char_indices.next();
        Self {
            char_indices,
            chunk_start: 0,
            s,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for CamelCaseSplit<'a> {
    type Item = &'a str;
    
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // The input is exhausted
        if self.chunk_start == self.s.len() {
            return None;
        }
        // Find the next uppercase letter position OR the end of the string
        let chunk_end = if let Some((chunk_end, _)) = self.char_indices.by_ref().skip_while(|(_, c)| !c.is_uppercase()).next() {
            chunk_end
        } else {
            self.s.len()
        };
        let chunk = &self.s[self.chunk_start..chunk_end];
        self.chunk_start = chunk_end;
        return Some(chunk);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let split = CamelCaseSplit::new("AaaBbCc");
    for c in split {
        println!("{c}");
        // Aaa
        // Bb
        // Cc
    }
}


Thanks, lazyness isn't 100% critical (though it's great see how to do it) the issue is more that I'm working with large strings that will be split into a lot of pieces so avoiding the need to allocate new memory (especially an entire new string) for each split is a significant advantage. Thanks for the great answer.

Sure thing. I mentioned laziness specifically because you can of course just do this in a for loop. But if you need to re-use it a lot or split the iteration up an iterator can be handy. Note that there was a bug in the original code. It would always produce an empty chunk at the beginning. The fix is just the newly edited in first two lines of the constructor.

I believed that this cannot be achieved through any single method on String. But there is a work-around as follows:
let s = String::from("AaaBbCc");
let s_reversed = s.chars().rev().collect::<String>();
let blocks = s_reversed
    .split_inclusive(|c: char| c.is_uppercase())
    // reverse each block in the iterator...
    .map(|block| block.chars().rev().collect::<String>())
    // and then reverse the whole iterator
    .rev();
for block in blocks {
    println!("{}", block)
}


That does work, but it's very inefficient. Rust's split iterators are both lazy and don't require any memory allocation , so they're extremely efficient. By contrast your code processes the string twice and assigns memory for it twice (and a bit as many small String's are less efficient than one big String due to needing to store their size and a pointer each) it does work but it's easy to do better. e.g:

`let s = String::from("AaaBbCc");
let blocks = {
let mut blocks = Vec::new();
let mut last_split_at = 0;
for (index, c) in s.chars().enumerate() {
if c.is_uppercase() {
blocks.push(&s[last_split_at..index]);
last_split_at = index;
}
}
    if last_split_at != s.len() - 1 {
        blocks.push(&s[last_split_at..s.len()])
    }

    blocks
};

for block in blocks {
    println!("{block}")
}

`

which creates a Vec of &str's, it's still far less efficient than split as it's not lazy and needs to allocate space for the Vec but it''s quite a bit faster and more memory efficient than reversing, collecting, splitting, reversing, collecting and then splitting again.
You might be right about it not being possible to do this with split but I'll keep the question open for now in case there's something we're missing (or a more efficient work around)

"Very efficient" and "very inefficient" without specific benchmarks is meaningless. Depending on the use case, it may also just be "good enough".

@RichardNeumann it is very inefficient relative to the optimal implementation as it involves a lot of unnecessary memory allocation. That doesn't necessarily make it a bad implementation. For example, it has the advantage of being quite a bit simpler than isaactfa's custom iterator solution, and as you say depending on the use case that might be fine (here I'm dealing with large strings and lots of splits so it isn't great) but just because the efficiency may not be required for some problems or that you may prefer simplicity over efficiency doesn't change the fact that it is inefficient.
